# Configuration of Hbase in Hue

Tags: hbase, hue

I have a standalone Hbase with some data in it and I want to access it via Hue. I am using 14.04 ubuntu.

I followed this tutorial http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-manage-hbase-data-via-hue/ and Have installed Hue.

But I am not able to have HBase and Thrift Service 1 initiated. When I execute the command:

sudo apt-get install hbase-thrift

E: Unable to locate package hbase-thrift

When I go into the admin console of Hue, at the step 1 check configuration: I got this errors, not sure if it is related.

Could not connect to localhost:9090 (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('Could not connect to localhost:9090',)

I think I need to initiate hbase-thrift package.

How should I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Cloudera Manager the HBase Thrift Service 1 can be added in one click in the HBase service page.

If installing with packages and the repo is not added, you could find them directly here, e.g. with Ubuntu: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/ubuntu/precise/amd64/cdh/pool/contrib/h/hbase/

Answer (score 0):

If HBase allready installed on your system, then you need simply initiate this process, just run following comand in your shell:
'/usr/bin/hbase thrift start'
and restart the HUE.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and i solved with:

1) Change the line contain the directory of HBase in Hue.ini file

**- hbase_conf_dir=/where you installed/Hbase/conf**

2) start HBase thrift server.

**- #hbase thrift start**

3) check if the server running (the port number by default 9090)

**- #netstat -ntulp | grep 9090**

3)start Hue

**- #Hue runserver**